# Why does this append only work if I console log a bad variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am relatively new with jquery, and am trying to change an up and down arrow on a js accordion on each click, unfortunately, I have run into an error where it only works if I console.log a bad variable. Does anyone have any guidance as to what I might be doing wrong when I onclick="embiggen(1)" for example if its accordion id one?

```
function arrowup(id){
$('#downarrow'+id).remove();
$('#dropdown'+id).append('</a>');
$('#dropdown'+id).append('<i id="uparrow'+ id +'" class="icon-1 icon-chevron-up">');
}

function arrowdown(id){
$('#uparrow'+id).remove();
$('#dropdown'+id).append('</a>');
$('#dropdown'+id).append('<i id="downarrow'+ id +'" class="icon-1 icon-chevron-down">');
}


//Switches the arrows
function embiggen(id){

var up = $('#uparrow'+id).length;
if (up == 1){
    arrowdown(id);
    console.log(i see you);
}
var down = $('#downarrow'+id).length;
if (down == 1){
    arrowup(id);
}

}
```

Comment: I should note It also swallows up the icon with the previous link, which is why the </a> is there, this does not help so if you have any guidance as to that it would be amazing. (I updated to the latest jquery if that helps.)

Comment: Why not make the arrow a CSS pseudo element and just toggle a class on the container?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It's a bit hard to tell what's going on. Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PkKfj/ is the closest I can get it, it will at least give you a accurate Idea... needs more things to work properly..

Comment: @Jay, I posted my answer. It doesn't solve your particular problem but it'll give you a new perspective. And it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
$('#dropdown'+id).append('</a>');
```

It should be like that :

```
$('#dropdown'+id).append('<a/>');
```

Minor change, but i just tested it and `</a>` doesn't work.

Also, the `<i>` need a closed tag like that :

```
.append('<i id="downarrow'+ id +'" class="icon-1 icon-chevron-down"></i>')
```

Comment: the `<i>` should probly have a `/` too. Still, im not sure about this.

Comment: Didn't help for reference, this is what is before the initial icon:

<a id="dropdown0" onclick="embiggen(0)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse0"> Random bullcrap &nbsp;</a>

Comment: Does not work, however I do have nice clean code now on the icon front (the </a> was to kill the link, which did not work..)

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, here's how to do it with pseudo elements. I'm using CSS arrows but you could just give them a fixed width and height and use a background image as icon.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/oyemaj/1/edit

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Porta est magna adipiscing...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion h2 {
  position: relative;
  padding: .5em;  
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: blue;
}

.accordion h2.open:after {
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.accordion p { display: none }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.accordion h2').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').next().slideToggle();
});
```

Yup, that's all the jQuery you need if you use this approach.

Comment: Yes, you can use CSS sprites in the pseudo elements. I'll leave that up to you.