# Why does this JQuery only work if I console.log a bad variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new with jquery, and am trying to change an up and down arrow on a js accordion on each click, unfortunately, I have run into an error where it only works if I console.log a bad variable. Does anyone have any guidance as to what I might be doing wrong when I onclick="embiggen(1)" for example if its accordion id one?

There are some other issues surrounding the html, but specifically why is this only working if I console.log;?

```
function arrowup(id){
$('#downarrow'+id).remove();
$('#dropdown'+id).append('</a>');
$('#dropdown'+id).append('<i id="uparrow'+ id +'" class="icon-1 icon-chevron-up">');
}

function arrowdown(id){
$('#uparrow'+id).remove();
$('#dropdown'+id).append('</a>');
$('#dropdown'+id).append('<i id="downarrow'+ id +'" class="icon-1 icon-chevron-down">');
}


//Switches the arrows
function embiggen(id){

var up = $('#uparrow'+id).length;
if (up == 1){
    arrowdown(id);
    console.log(i see you);
}
var down = $('#downarrow'+id).length;
if (down == 1){
    arrowup(id);
}

}
```

Comment: So what have you tried since your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803753/why-does-this-append-only-work-if-i-console-log-a-bad-variable)? This looks essentially the same.

Comment: The answers I got on my last question were actually for the html issue, and not the js.. I needed to focus on the main issue.. and I tried a whole bunch of rewriting to no avail, as well as everything suggested in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad `console.log()` makes it "work" because the error breaks the script execution before entering the second `if` statement.

---

### Fixing the real issue

`down == 1` is always `true`. You should use an `else` statement:

```
if ($('#uparrow'+id).length){
    arrowdown(id);
} else if ($('#downarrow'+id).length){
    arrowup(id);
}
```

---

### Understanding it

`down == 1` is always true independently of `up == 1`. Here's your logic explained in pseudo-code in both scenarios:

```
var up = 1, down = 0;
if (up) { down = 1; up = 0; } //enters this block, down now is 1
if (down) { down = 0; up = 1; } //enters this block as down == 1
```

```
var up = 0, down = 1;
if (up) { down = 1; up = 0; } //doesn't enter this block
if (down) { down = 0; up = 1; } //enters this block as down == 1
```

You just have put an `else` in there so the execution flow does not enter the second if statement in case the first one succeeds.

```
if (up) {}
else if (down) {}
```

---

### Truthy/Falsy values

To explain why I'm using `.length` isolated inside the conditional statement: in JavaScript, the number `0` is a falsy value and `1` is truthy, hence these can be used directly inside the `if` statement and it will be interpreted based on the internal [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) algorithm logic. Obviously you can `== 1` if you feel like, that's more clear though slightly redundant.

---

### A possibly simpler way around

Going a little off-topic, but your goal can most likely be achieved in an easier way. I may be oversimplifying your logic, but depending on your intents you may just toggle between those two classes:

```
function embiggen(id) {
    $('#arrow'+id).toggleClass('icon-chevron-up icon-chevron-down');
}
```

Then, you'd no longer have to create a new `#downarrow`/`#uparrow` element each time the function is called. If said arrow has JS behavior attached, you can check which logic to execute through an `if` statement using [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Comment: You seem to be a god amongst men... thank you for solving this for me... Any idea why the anchor tag was wrapping around the icon earlier?

Comment: No problem. From your given code, I don't see how that would happen. If anything, post another question with a http://jsfiddle.net and I'll take a look. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

It works because when an error occurs, JavaScript skips the rest of your function body.

The problem in your case is that the function `arrowdown()` creates `#downarrow+id`, making the next condition truthy and calling the function `arrowup()`.

You either need an alternative branch, using [Fabricio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804416/1338292), or return immediately after making changes to the DOM that would otherwise change the state:

```
function embiggen(id) {
    if ($('#uparrow'+id).length) {
        return arrowdown(id);
    }
    if ($('#downarrow'+id).length) {
        return arrowup(id);
    }
    // ehm, something else happened?
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? With the `return` it will never get into the second `if` statement. Though I preferred your first version with `else`, +1 for the alternative way `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks, you already had the `else` so lest our answers look exactly the same I chose an alternative :)